# Problem displaying array. Everything is placed into a separate row, but not into separate columns?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a text based minesweeper program as a homework assignment. I'm having problems displaying the array and haven't figured out what I'm missing. Basically I'm trying to just get the program to display "5" in rows and columns to make sure I've written it correctly. However, it is displaying a string of 100 5's in one long column. I believe it's multiplying the number of rows against the number of columns, it's only supposed to be 10 by 10. What is causing this error?

Thanks for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_ROWS = 10;
const int MAX_COLUMNS = 10;
const int EMPTY_SQUARE_DIGIT = 0;
const char EMPTY_SQUARE_SYMBOL = '_';
const int BOMB_DIGIT = -1;
const char BOMB_SYMBOL = '#';

void fillTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void displayTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);

int main(void)
{
int gameBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];

srand(time(NULL));

fillTheGameBoard(gameBoard);
displayTheGameBoard(gameBoard);




system("pause");

return 0;
}


void fillTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)

        for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
        {
            board[row][column] = 5;
        }
} 


void displayTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)

        for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
        {
            cout << board[row][column] << " " << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` - you should watch [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Using all UPPERCASE compile time constants is antipattern, you create the problem it originally tried to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newline is printed for every cell.

```
cout << board[row][column] << " " << endl;
```

This explains the "Everything is placed into a separate row" bit. You probably know what to fix now.

```
for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
        cout << board[row][column] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked, I was just looking at the problem wrong. Thanks again!